# How to reach fields from populated response?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, axios

I have two DB

```
const MentorSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        firstName: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            min: 2,
            max: 50
        },
        lastName: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            min: 2,
            max: 50
        },
        age: {
            type: Number,
            required: true,
        },
        qualification: {
            type: String,
            required: false
        },
        yearOfExpierience: {
            type: Number,
            required: true,
        },
        pricePerLesson: {
            type: Number,
            required: false
        },
        description: {
          type: String,
          required: false,
          max: 300
        },
        email: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            max: 50,
            unique: true
        },
        password: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            min: 5
        },
        picturePath: {
            type: String,
            default: " "
        },
        country: {
            type: String,
            required: false
        },
        city: {
            type: String,
            required: false
        },
        availableOnline: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: true
        },
        bestMentor: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: false
        },
        groupLessons: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: true,
        }
    }, {
        toJSON: {
          virtuals: true,
        },
        toObject: {
          virtuals: true
        }
      }
);



MentorSchema.virtual('blogs', {
    ref: 'Blog',
    localField: '_id',
    foreignField: 'mentor',
    justOne: false
  });


const Mentor = mongoose.model("Mentor", MentorSchema);

export default Mentor;
```

and

```
const BlogSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    mentor: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Mentor',
        required: 'true'
    },
    firstName: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Mentor'
    },
    text: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
})

const Blog = mongoose.model("Blog", BlogSchema);

export default Blog;
```

and controller

```
try {
        let query;

        query = Blog.find().populate('mentor');

        const blog = await query;
        res.status(200).json(blog)
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json({error: err});
    }
```

When i make a get request i get a response like this

"_id": "643a7df77be2af848bb42487",
"mentor": {
"_id": "64343ab14dc32790de9a5940",
"firstName": "Ivan",
"lastName": "Petro",
}

on page i have to show firstName of mentor, how to reach it?

http://localhost:3001/blog?mentor.firstName doesn`t work

I tried to make a get request like http://localhost:3001/blog?mentor.firstName but it doesn`t work

Comment: just to clarify, is your expected result to call that `url` and only get the mentor's first name?

Comment: i have to call url **http://localhost:3001/blog** and get mentor first name, last name and blog text.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [template string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```js
const data = { "_id": "643a7df77be2af848bb42487", "mentor": { "_id": "64343ab14dc32790de9a5940", "firstName": "Ivan", "lastName": "Petro" } };

const endpoint = `http://localhost:3001/blog?${data.mentor.firstName}`;

console.log(endpoint);
```

Comment: I have to make a request on server, get all blogs and show them. I have code like this ``const resp = await axios.get(`http://localhost:3001/blog`)
    .then(function(response) {
      console.log(response);
    })`` How to get mentor first name here?

Answer (score 0):

If you have:

```
const resp = await axios.get(`http://localhost:3001/blog`)     
    .then(function(response) {       
        // response will be an array of Blog with the mentor property populated
        response?.map(blog => console.log(blog.mentor));   
    })
```